# Change href tag based on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**EDIT: The buttons in the corner will not be submitting the search. The go button would still be clicked to submit it.**

So, I'm working on a little project when I'm bored at work. It isn't meant to be anything serious and I'm teaching a bit of javascript, jquery, html and css as I go (Thanks to you fine folks of course). This part I can't figure out, or find anything about.

My page is: http://afrohorse.netau.net/

As of right now, I have a form that when you type in, and press go, it will search google. I plan on having it so I can click one of four buttons (located on each corner of the page) and it will change where it searches when you submit. Here is the code for my form.

```
<form onsubmit="location.href='https://www.google.ca/#q=' + document.getElementById('myInput').value; return false;">
   <input type="text" id="myInput" class="search left" value="" autofocus/>
   <button class="go"><span>GO!</span></button>
</form>
```

So, Ideally, I would like to have it so "https://www.google.ca/#q=" would change to "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" after clicking the youtube button. Is this doable? If so how would be the easiest way?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually better off removing the form and just using a button.  You could do what you have above like this...

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" class="search left" value="" autofocus/>
<button class="go" id="search-button">GO!</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {

    $("#search-button").on("click", function() {

        var query = $("#myInput").val();

        // if using Google search...
        location.href = "https://www.google.ca/#q=" + query;

        // if using Youtube search...
        location.href = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query;

    }); 
});
```

Comment: I'm still quite new to JS and I feel a bit lost. I did a bit of googling and looking around Stackoverflow but still cant figure how to implement this. Although, it definitely looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Also, the buttons on the corner will not be submitting it. They will just be updating where it goes, and you still click the "go" button. Im not sure if your example does that. It looks like it would use several different buttons.

Comment: I don't actually see anything on your site other than the search box and go button.  The above code can be modified easily to go to different locations from the 1 button, but I don't see how you expect to know which search to perform.

Comment: I have yet to add the buttons as I'm trying to figure out the best way to do so before I do. In the end, there will be one button in each corner (google, google image, youtube, and something else) you click the button and it highlights it. You type in the box, and hit go, then it will search the selected option.

Comment: I've modified the code so it's just a generic "go" button, and added examples of a Google search and a Youtube search.  Until you give us the rest of the page then we can't help you with the code to decide what search to use.  You need to get that in place first.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it diffirently. I would give the button/ an ID. If this button/ is clicked i would check what button, so youtube or google. Then get the input and send the user to the correct link. so something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="btn_google">google it</a>
<a href="#" id="btn_youtube">youtube it</a>
<input type="text" id="input_search" placeholder="What are you searching for?">
```

the JS:

```
$('btn_google').addEvent("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href='http://www.google.ca/#q='.$('input_search').value;
});
$('btn_youtube').addEvent("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href='http://www.youtube.ca/results?search_query='.$('input_search').value;
});
```

btw i use mootools :) so the events are abit diffirent in jquery